# Unit conversion using Python

Tags: python

I am going through Learn Python the Hard Way, On Ex-5 Study Drills, it states

> Try to write some variables that convert inches and pounds to centimeters and kilos. Do not just type in the measurements. Work out the math in Python.

So far I have done this:

```
inches = 1
centimeters = 1
convert = centimeters * 2.54
print inches
print centimeters 
print "1 inch is %s centimeters." % convert
```

Now that will display the conversion of 1 inch, How would I be able to change it so that the user would input an amount in inches or centimeters, and it would correctly display the conversion?

And am I right in thinking that for it to successfully convert values, I would have to enter the values in manually or is there a way to do this already made in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to lookup for a specified unit:

```
amount, unit = input('Enter amount with units: ').split()[:2]
converted_data = int(amount) * {'in': 2.54, 'cm': 0.39}[unit]
```

Comment: Could you explain this in simple terms for myself, I have just picked up the book to learn and know nothing of Programming.

Comment: Basically a dictionary maps the keys to values. I mapped the units to the multiplicative factor to get the other unit. The input was simply split at the whitespace in order to get the first two words in the string, one for amount one for unit.

Answer (score 6):

There are libraries for handling units. [pint](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/) is one for Python:

```py
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
my_size = 1.74 * ureg.meter
print(my_size)  # 1.74 meter
print(my_size.to(ureg.inch))  # 68.503937007874 inch
```

The advantage is that the variables themselves have the information about which unit was used. This continues even if you divide:

```py
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
distance = 40123 * ureg.meter
time = 1.2 * ureg.hour
speed = distance / time
print(speed)  # 33435.833333333336 meter / hour
print(speed.to(ureg.inch / ureg.hour))  # 1316371.3910761154 inch / hour
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `input()` method (wrapped in `float()` method to convert data to integer

```
m_inch = float(input("Enter the amount in inches: ")) # will collection user data in inches

m_cm = m_inch*2.54 # converts from inches to cm

# rest of your code
```

N.B. I have used `float` type for input, but you could use `int()` to wrap as well....Does this help?

Comment: Make sure to include the "input" in a try except block. For example, if a string is entered (e.g. "asd") then a ValueError exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "Bob Jones"
age = 39
height = 74 # in inches
height_in_cm = height * 2.54
weight = 220 # in pounds
weight_in_kg = weight * 0.453592
eyes = "blue"
teeth ="white"
hair = "light brown"

print(f"Let's talk about {name}.")
print(f"He's {height} inches tall which is roughly {round(height_in_cm)} centimeters.")
print(f"He weighs {weight} pounds which is about {round(weight_in_kg)} kilograms.")
print(f"Actually, that's his target weight after six months of intermittent fasting.")
print(f"He's got {eyes} eyes and {hair} hair.")
print(f"His teeth are usually {teeth} depending on how much coffee he drinks.")
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that the user asked; "And am I right in thinking that for it to successfully convert values, I would have to enter the values in manually or is there a way to do this already made in Python?" And code-only answers without more information are not as useful as answers to the questions. Can you add some notes about what you did in this code and why you did it?

Answer (score 0):

```
centimeters = int(input("Enter your height in CM "))
meters = centimeters / 100
print ("You are %r meters long" % (meters))
```

This asks user to enter height in cm, remember 1m is equal to 100cm. 
So, we divide 180 by 100 to get the meters for example, if user enters 180 cm
1.8 meters will be printed.